# Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

Attempting to compile and debug the Android application I am working on resulted in the following errors:

Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0.

my Google Play Services and Google Repository packages are up to date

Comment: Please try using some other version 7.8 or so

Comment: @Renjith : Try to rebuild or clean project..!!

Comment: post your gradle file here.